# Sync threads with Posix Semaphores

Tags: c, multithreading

Hi I am trying to make 3 thread that will print different messages multiple times. Then sync them, so to print for example ONE TWO THREE ONE TWO THREE ONE TWO THREE... When I run the program sometimes it is not correct and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
  sem_t sema, semb, semc;


void *printone(void *arg) 
{
  printf("<ONE>");
  sem_wait(&semc);
  sem_post(&semb);
}

void *printtwo(void *arg) 
{
  printf("<TWO>");
  sem_wait(&sema);
  sem_post(&semc);
}

void *printthree(void *arg) 
{
  printf("<THREE>");
  sem_wait(&semb);
  sem_post(&sema);
}

main() 

{
  pthread_t th1,th2,th3;
  int i;

    sem_init(&sema,0,1);
    sem_init(&semb,0,0);
    sem_init(&semc,0,0);

  for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    pthread_create( &th1, NULL, printone, (void *) 1); 
    pthread_create( &th2, NULL, printtwo, (void *) 2); 
    pthread_create( &th3, NULL, printthree, (void *) 3); 

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);
    pthread_join(th3, NULL);
  }



  pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a workable approach: each thread waits on one semaphore, and later posts another to let the next thread run.  For that to work, however, each thread should wait for its semaphore *before* performing its work (i.e. print its message).

Additionally, it looks like your thread functions are using the wrong semaphores.  For `printone()` to run first, it must wait on the semaphore that you initialize with value 1.  For `printtwo()` to run next, it must wait on whichever semaphore `printone()` posts to.  Similarly, for `printthree()`.

As a secondary matter, if your thread functions are not going to use their argument, then it would be best to pass `NULL` as the third argument to `pthread_create()`.